# express session connect-mssql-v2 dynamic table

Tags: node.js, express-session

I am using `connect-mssql-v2` with express session to persist the session in a database. So for every login there is a sid created like this in the Sessions table:

[image]

I am fine with this and I understand there these columns need to stay as it is. The session value is probably fed directly to passport session function. But I want to be able to select all the columns belonging to a particular userID. Join on this table and perform various operations based on the userID. The userID value is present in the session column but I would love to have a separate column for userID. From the documentation of the library there are some options to customize the table name but it seems like besies that there is not much else that we can do. Is there a way to customize `connect-mssql-v2` to store userID in a separate column?

[image]